"Being Jewish" - born from a Jewish woman or having a Jewish mother?
This sounds frivolous but it's a genuine distinction.
One practical ramification is regarding conversion for a child born via surrogacy, whether the birth mother is Jewish and the egg donor is not, or vice-versa (depending on the halachic debate regarding motherhood).
A Rabbi I spoke to said it was clear to him that there was no inherent connection between motherhood and Jewishness (i.e. that Jewishness could simply be a consequence of emerging from a Jewish womb), and that was why he felt the Gemara in Yevamot 78a was not relevant to the surrogacy debate.
Are there any indications or proofs either way? Does anyone discuss this?
(Looking at some of the Rishonim regarding the sugya of הורתו שלא בקדושה ולידתו בקדושה (יבמות צח.), explaining why such individuals are Jewish, the Rishonim's choice of expression focuses on the circumstances of the child's birth, rather than who their mother is. For example, the תוס' רי"ד says "דהא לא נתגייר אלא בקדושה נולד".
But I don't consider that to be such a strong proof.)
I tried looking for this halacha in the Rambam, and in Tur/SA, to see if their choice of wording could imply one way or another - but I wasnt successful in finding this fundamental halacha in either.

Good question Chani. Your answer is not so much going to be found in Shas, except by hints. You are asking about when and what determines the state of being of the individual. This is more in the realm of the “reasons behind the commandments” (טעמי המצות) and is therefore in the realm of kabbalistic tradition.

@YaacovDeane you're probably right... However, the sea of torah is vast, and it's not beyond the realm of possibility that someone has researched this question somewhere and found some indicators, however obscure... that's what I'm hoping at least

Note the Halacha nowadays is that we convert the child in any case (whether the surrogate was Jewish or the eggs were Jewish)

You're aware of the modern-day debate and the sources cited; you linked to it. So what is your question, precisely? It appears you're trying to nitpick the exact language used for "born Jewish"; it appears that all the poskim trying to apply analogies and precedents felt that's a stronger approach than dissecting the Gemara's wording.

As Rabbi Chaim Brisker liked to say, Sheva Brachos needs a "panim chadashos." Elsewhere, the Gemara says that ashes of meat don't have the status of the meat, as "panim chadashos" have arrived. So if there aren't any new guests at Sheva Brachos, why not just burn a piece of meat? Aha, says Rav Chaim ... it must be that context matters too when parsing the Gemara's language ...

@Shalom I don't understand... the modern debate is regarding שאר. I am asking regarding יהדות , they aren't necessarily the same thing..?

They are treated the same halachically to the very best of my knowledge. Never heard of anyone trying to split that distinction. Overwhelmingly, the question is not "can the product of a surrogate pregnancy marry a relative of the host/egg mother" (pretty easy to be machmir on that one, there are lots of other frum singles); the question every posek gets all the time is whether they need a conversion if one mother's Jewish and the other isn't, as frequently happens.

There are arguments both ways.  Some say the legal mother is the birth mother, because a midrash says that Dinah was conceived in Rachel's womb, and Joseph in Leah’s womb, but that God switched the embryos so Rachel could give birth to a son, Joseph. [Targum Yonatan on Genesis 30:21] The basis is that all six times Leah has a son, the Torah says:  “Leah conceived and bore a son”.  But when it comes to Dinah, it just says:  “Leah bore a daughter”.  Yet, the Torah clearly refers to Leah as Dinah's mother [Gen. 34:1].  So we learn that she who gives birth is the mother, not she who produced the egg.
The Talmud says that when Esther’s mother became pregnant with her, her father died, and when she was born, her mother died. [Megillah 13a]  This could mean that Esther’s mother did not become her mother until Esther was born.  The Midrash says "If someone begins to perform a commandment and does not complete it, and someone else comes and completes it, the one who has completed it gets the credit. [Deut. R. 8:4]  Here, the one who completes the task is the birth mother, so she is the mother.
So far, most rabbinical authorities rule that the one giving birth is the mother.  But there are other arguments.  The discussion continues.

In terms of halacha, your reference to the principle of completing the action is excellent Maurice. The Lubavitcher Rebbe discusses this principle in regard to the requirement that Moshiach build the third and final Temple which must be eternal physically and materially. The Rebbe doesn’t describe it as “getting credit” for the act. Rather, that the object of the act is converted from its previous state of being into that of the one completing the act. From this point of departure, the Rebbe says that Moshiach must be eternal physically and materially in order to fulfill that obligation.

It cannot be proved from the case of Dina's birth even if we adopt the language of the midrash. Both Leah and Rachel were Jewish women. How can one make conclusions regarding cases of non-Jewish biological mother or non-Jewish surrogate mother?

@YDJ -- You can also say that the argument of completing the mitzvah doesn't apply because women are not commanded to have children.  As I said, the discussion continues.

...and Hashem said that Sarah will give birth.

My question is not regarding Motherhood. It's regarding יהדות. I'm aware of these מראה מקומות

The Rabbi you are quoting is suggesting that a child born through surrogacy could have a Jewish mother but not be Jewish, or have a non-Jewish mother but be Jewish, as emerging from the womb of an unrelated woman is what defines Jewishness.
Aside from this possibility not having a clear rationale, I believe it can be proved wrong from the very Gemara you reference (Yevamot 78a-b). The Gemara says that if עובר לאו ירך אמו (a foetus is not considered ‘a limb of its mother,’ but an independent entity), the foetus of a woman who converts to Judaism during pregnancy requires its own immersion, and this is achieved in the mikveh together with the mother, as the body of the mother is not a chatzitza (blockage).
Were the suggestion you make correct, even if the body of the mother were a a chatzitza, the baby should be Jewish just by emerging from the womb of a Jewish mother.
So in short, the answer is that "being Jewish" is a function of having a Jewish mother.

Nice one :) I don't think that's conclusive, however. The gemara implies that according to the opinion עובר לאו ירך אמו, the child is a convert even before birth - meaning, according to that opinion, conception determines Jewishness, not birth. So my question regarding Jewishness would be the opposite case, according to that opinion. (meaning, why was the child a gentile until his mother's tevila? does that opinion hold that the child was a gentile because he was conceived to a non-jew, or because his (egg) mother was a non-jew? I hope I'm being clear)

You are right that either the egg mother or conception determines Jewishness, certainly not birth (this is true according to both opinions in the Gemara). But if I understand correctly, your question as to whether it is the egg mother or conception that is important, is the classic question as to whether the halachic mother is the egg mother or the one who carries the feotus (= the one who the child was conceived to). I agree that this gemara is not conclusive regarding this question.
